# Map tel: links to get request in Firefox

Tags: firefox, protocol-handler

We have a PBX system in our office that can be triggered to originate a call to a given number on your extension whilst you are logged into the User Control Panel (so you get the right cookies) by visiting `http://pbx.host/some/path?number=0123456789`.

Is there an extension or any guides on writing an extension for Firefox to pass `tel:` links to a given url.

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

- Open `regedit`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tel\shell\open\command`
- Double-click on `(Default)`
- Copy and save the current value as a backup
- Replace it by :
  `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "http://pbx.host/some/path?number="%l""`

I haven't tested it so errors are possible, but let me know how it works.